# Correct way (if any!) to apply preprocessing to hold out dataset

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, scikit-learn, predictor, hyperparameter

After cross validation and grid search the below are the desired pipeline steps and hyper-params for my model.

```
k= 19
C= 1.6
model = make_pipeline(SelectKBest(score_func=chi2,
                                k=k), 
                     StandardScaler(),
                    LogisticRegression(C=C,
                                      solver='lbfgs',
                                      max_iter=100))
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
```

Is the prediction step correctly applied?

- Should one remove the k best features from X_test prior to
  prediction ? &
- Should data standard scaler be applied to X_test prior to
  prediction

I've read plenty of advice regarding not using the test set as part of the learning process of your model and I think the above might be one of the cases. Really looking for best practices.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the best way. Each pipeline step has `fit` and `predict` methods that operate on train and test sets separately. For each pipeline step, the `predict` method uses learnt parameters from its previous `fit` call, which was called using the training set.